# Explicit instantiation of function with auto->decltype approach

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

I want to create template function that would be able to extract any property of struct A.

Here is Source.h

```
struct B
{
    int bbb;
};

struct C
{
    double ccc;
};

struct A
{
    B b;
    C c;
};

template <class R>
auto foo(A* str, R getter) -> decltype(str->*getter);
```

Now I want use explicit instantiation approach for foo

Here comes Source.cpp:

```
#include "Source.h"

template <class R>
auto foo(A* str, R getter) -> decltype(str->*getter)
{
    return str->*getter;
}
```

If we look at Main.cpp, we can see, that without explicit instantiation in the code block above we get link error:

```
//MAIN.cpp
#include "Source.h"

void main()
{
    A a;
    a.b.bbb = 7;
    auto z = foo(&a, &A::b);
}
```

Now my question is how to explicitly instantiate foo for &A::b and &A::c types.
I have tried tons of variants but nothing works. I am in visual studio 2015.

P.S. Oh, and one more. Can we make foo with default argument for 
`R = decltype(&A::b)` ?

Comment: Is there any reason not to write the implementation of `foo` in `Source.h`?

Comment: yes, that is why there is explicit instantiation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
template B &foo(A*, B A::*);
template C &foo(A*, C A::*);
```

As for the default argument, you need defaults for both the type and the value:

```
template <class R = B A::*>
auto foo(A* str, R getter = &A::b) -> decltype(str->*getter);
```

Comment: Sorry but i still get link error
from main i call auto z = foo(&a, &A::b); and error

Comment: @Demaunt [It works fine here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7NJUNZSj1WOg7bWd). What exactly is the error?

Comment: 1) Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "struct B & __cdecl foo<struct B A::*>(struct A *,struct B A::*)" (??$foo@PQA@@UB@@@@YAAAUB@@PAUA@@PQ1@U0@@Z) referenced in function _main ConsoleApplication2 ...

2) Warning C4667 'B &foo(A *,B A::* )': no function template defined that matches forced instantiation

Comment: perhaps another "feature" from Microsoft compiler, guess I am done with this feature, because the project I am working on depends on MVSC

Comment: @Demaunt that warning is extremely fishy (and should be a hard error as well). Have you made sure to put the explicit instantiations after the function's definition in `Source.cpp`?

Comment: My code is EXACTLY the same as from wandbox (i even copy pasted it for all three files and still get the error)

Comment: @Demaunt this looks like [this MSVC bug related to `decltype`](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1349269/msvc-2015-cannot-instantiate-function-template-involving-decltype-new). The bad news is that it is still not fixed.

Comment: well, at least I know how to explicitly instantiate decltyped functions using proper compliers. Thank you very much